# Mudar selector de custom spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

Criei um `custom spinner` e um `custom dropdown spinner`, ao utilizá-los, o selector ficá quase que invisível e a cor dele também não ajuda. ***Eu queria que o meu seletor do spinner fosse maior, poderia ser do tamanho padrão e queria outra cor, para se sobre sair ao fundo do layout.*** *(Isto que está em negrito é o meu problema)*

Tentei passar uma referência de cor para o atributo no xml `android:dropDownSelector` e mesmo assim não funcionou. Vou colocar imagens aqui de dois spinners.

[image: Spinner não selecionado]

Esta imagem se refere a um spinner padrão. Criado com este layout: `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` e depois o layout de dropdown configurado desta forma: `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` no adapter. Na imagem acima o spinner não foi tocado pelo usuário, a imagem abaixo se refere ao mesmo spinner só que com a diferença que ele está sendo tocado pelo usuário.

[image: Spinner selecionado]

---

Agora se por acaso eu utilizo um custom spinner e um custom dropdown para o adapter, o seletor fica quase invisível como eu disse. Vamos ver agora imagens de como ficou meu custom spinner.
[image: Custom Spinner não selecionado]

O mesmo custom spinner abaixo só que agora selecionado.
[image: Custom Spinner selecionado]

Abaixo segue o código do meu custom spinner e do custom spinner dropdown(Isto vai configurado no adapter)

**custom_spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

custom_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#232323"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***Mais uma vez lembrando. Quero que o seletor do meu `custom spinner` seja maior e tenha uma cor diferente para sobre sair ao fundo. O tamanho do seletor poderia ser do tamanho do seletor padrão. Também gostaria de saber por que quando usei um `custom spinner` o tamanho do seletor ficou quase invisível e não do tamanho original.***

---

layout do fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#0F2028"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchButtonConcluidoIM"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="@string/concluido"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textOff="@string/nao"
    android:textOn="@string/sim"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPrimario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/primario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#55b76b"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPrimario"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSecundario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/secundario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#55b76b"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerSecundario"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewLeitura"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/leitura"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextLeitura"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/fields_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPolaridade"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/polaridade"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPolaridade"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/fields_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewObs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/observacao"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextObs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/fields_border"
                    android:ems="10"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Lucas, dê uma olhada nessa pergunta do SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703233/style-android-spinner. Ali ele queria estilizar o itens do dropdown, mas ele também estilizou a "setinha". Talvez seja um bom ponto de partida

Comment: @Wakim vou dar uma olhada e depois dou um retorno.

Comment: Outra dica, de uma inspecionada (com o ddms) na largura dos itens do dropdown. Talvez a largura dos itens esteja causando o problema e empurrando a seta.

Comment: Será? Eu coloquei o meu `TextView` do `custom spinner` como `match_parent`, vou tentar mudar depois para `wrap_content` e vê se tem alguma mudança quanto ao tamanho do seletor.

Comment: @Wakim o link não me ajudou...   :(    Quanto a mudança da largura dos `TextViews`, nada ocorreu, fiz os testes e o seletor continua pequeno.

Comment: Podia postar o layout da activity ou fragment?

Comment: @Wakim, vou editar minha pergunta com o layout do Fragment. Quanto a cor do seletor, eu consegui resolver. O meu problema ainda está no `custom layout`, ficou com a cor legal o seletor, só que continua pequeno. Se eu consegui resolver tudo aqui eu posto a solução. Estou navegando entre os `styles` da API do android para ver os componentes e fazer as mudanças.

Comment: @Wakim antes de eu editar a resposta com o código do `fragment`, você acha realmente necessário colocar aqui o código?

Comment: Codigo não é necessário, só o layout mesmo

Comment: Desculpa, fiz confusão com o código. Postando em 1...2...3...

Comment: Lucas, tenta trocar fill_parent por match_parent. O fill esta depreciado... Daqui a pouco eu dou uma olhada mais apurada no layout.

Comment: O Android Studio que coloca essa F#@R@#(*U(#@ de `fill_parent` automático aí eu esqueço de trocar para `match_parent`.

Comment: Pronto, peguei a pasta `res` e mandei um replace de `fill_parent` por `match_parent`. Todos os arquivos que tinham `fill_parent` foram alterados e mesmo assim o problema do seletor quase invisível no `custom layout` ainda persiste. Ainda bem que existe o replace :)

Comment: @Wakim achei o problema. \o/ Mas ainda não entendi o porque. Eu experimentei colocar o meu `spinner fora da `tablerow` e advinha? Taram!!! Lá estava o seletor grande. Por algum motivo ele dentro do `tablerow` fica daquele jeito.

Comment: @Wakim consegui resolver o problema. Vou postar a solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu tinha dito na minha perguta, o meu problema era:

> Eu queria que o meu seletor do spinner fosse maior, poderia ser do
>   tamanho padrão e queria outra cor, para se sobre sair ao fundo do
>   layout.

Vamos ao primeira caso, o seletor que estava quase invisível ser maior. O problema dele é que por estar em um `TableRow` o seletor ficava daquele tamanho. Fiz um teste com o `Spinner` fora do `TableRow` e o seletor ficou grande, do tamanho padrão. Para resolver este problema sem ter que trocar o `TableRow` que continha o `Spinner`, eu inseri o atributo `android:layout_weight="1"` e coloquei sua largura para `wrap_content`.

Vamos ao segundo caso, o seletor estava escuro, precisava que o mesmo ficasse mais claro. Tive que aplicar um `style` para os meus `Spinners`. O código do `style` contém os comentários para entendimento de como deixar o seletor mais claro ou trocar o seletor, caso deseje.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- Estilo padrão para o spinner dropdown. -->
        <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/CustomSpinnerStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Aqui eu defino estilo para todos os spinners do meu app, que será estendido pelo estilo que está na tag "parent" abaixo. -->
    <style name="CustomSpinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <!-- Aqui eu poderia definir um custom spinner selector por exemplo. Mas preferi utilizar o padrão mesmo. <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_spinner_selector</item> -->
    </style>

    <!--Este estilo aplica ao spinner o tema dark, ou seja, como o tema é DARK, as coisas terão as cores para se sobre sair ao escuro do tema.
        <style name="Widget.Holo.Spinner" parent="Widget.Spinner.DropDown">
            <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/spinner_background_holo_dark</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_holo_dark</item>
            <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_holo_dark</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
            <item name="android:popupPromptView">@android:layout/simple_dropdown_hint</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
            <item name="android:disableChildrenWhenDisabled">true</item>
        </style>
    -->

    <!-- Se eu tivesse um tema claro e quisesse aplicar um tema escuro para o spinner, eu deveria estender deste estilo e não o acima.
        <style name="Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" parent="Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/spinner_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownWidth">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:popupPromptView">@android:layout/simple_dropdown_hint</item>
    </style>
    -->

</resources>
```

Comment: Boa tarde. Em qual destes atributos eu seto um dropDownSelector personalizado Lucas Santos? Um png q criei por exemplo. Muito obrigado.